# Is there some python package to extract test description from pytest code

Tags: testing, extract, docstring

I search for some support to automate test specification from pytest code,

```
Example :
relay_cfg = [
    (
        2,
        RELAY_ACTION["BLINKS"],
        RELAY_CONDITION["WHEN"],
        [TRIGGER["WC_TREND_MONTHLY_ALARM_LEVEL_2"]],
        "Blinks",
        "Off",
        "On"
    ),
]

def test_api_relays_alarm_wc_monthly_l2(
    self,
    web_api_session,
    relay_id,
    action,
    condition,
    trigger,
    after_raise_alarm,
    before_raise_alarm,
    before_set_relay_config
):
    """step     1 : xxxxx """
    """expected 1 : xxxxx """
    
    web_api = web_api_session
    ret_value = True

    """step     2 : xxxxx """
    """expected 2 : xxxxx """
    res = web_api.data_acquisition_get_all_reading()
```

1. I search python package to extract all steps/expected , something like (not necessary exact) :
   [["step     1 : xxxxx ", "expected 1 : xxxxx "], ["step     2 : xxxxx ", "expected 2 : xxxxx "]]
2. is there some tools to extract docstring placed at many lines : not necessarily only at first bloc.